# instanceType attribute in Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, powershell, user-management, attributes

I need to change the instanceType attribute of a service account. If I try to change it from Active Directory Users and Computers console it's greyed out and if I try to change it via powershell with Set-Aduser i get "The attribute cannot be modified because it is owned by the system".

Anyone has any ideea on how can I change the instanceType attribute from 4 to 0 ?

Comment: Yes, there is an (unsupported) way of doing this, but `instanceType` is not the type of attribute value you would normally change, for any reason. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm going to guess that OP is trying to make the user account read-only?

Comment: This was only a task I was supposed to do and stumbled upon this error. I found several ways on how to change it but most of them said just what Mathias R. Jessen said, that i shouldn't be doing this.

Answer (score 5):

As you've found, the `instanceType` attribute is marked "system-only", since you could potentially mess with the replication state of the directory replica in which you modify this attribute.

## You probably shouldn't be doing this!

To circumvent this protection, add the following registry value on a Domain Controller:

```
Key:   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\NTDS\Parameters
Name:  "Allow System Only Change"
Type:  DWORD
Value: 0x1
```

You could use PowerShell for this:

```
Set-ItemProperty HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\NTDS\Parameters -Name "Allow System Only Change" -Value 1
```

Now you can modify the value of instanceType attributes on that DC. Either connect to that specific DC with LDP.exe/dsa.msc, or use the `-Server` parameter with the Active Directory module cmdlets.

Remember to remove the registry key after making your changes.

Comment: This is a request that I am supposed to do but thanks to you i can give a pertinent answer now why I cannot make this changes. Thank you.

Comment: Please dont forget to mark this as an answer.

Comment: I believe that even if you change the protection there is no guarantee that the attribute won't be changed by the system right after.